Where is the documentation on the extra attribute on a Range?
I just found out about C# ranges, thanks to VSCode Quick Fixes, which looks very nice (especially coming from Python). The one thing that I cannot find any documentation on, though, is the supplying of a list in that syntax.
In my code (as suggested by the Quick Fix), I can do this:
class Foo {
     private List<int> buffer;
     private buffer[] validBuffer;

     void SomeMethod() {
         validBuffer = [.. buffer];
     }
}

The range here .. is clear, but nowhere can I find documentation on the buffer part in [.. buffer].

This is not a range. It's more like the * operator in python, as in bigListOfStrings = [*someStrings, *someOtherStrings, 'other', 'elements'].

It's called spread element, here's some documentation on it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/collection-expressions#spread-element
